# Symbolic `show` for `SInt16`

Tags: haskell, sbv, symbolic-execution

I am looking for a way to turn an `SInt16` into an `SString`. For my use case, it is enough that it does the right thing for concrete values, i.e. I will only be looking at the `SString` result for concrete `SInt16`s.

I noticed there is a `Show` instance for `SInt16`, which (of course) returns a `String`. It is almost good enough for my needs: for symbolic values, it returns `"<symbolic> :: SInt16"` and for concrete values e.g. 42, it returns `"42 :: SInt16"`. So if not for that pesky type tag, I could use `literal . show @SInt16` as my `SInt16 -> SString` function.

Is there a better way than editing the return value of `show` to cut out the type tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```hs
import Data.SBV
import Data.SBV.String

toString :: (SymVal a, Show a) => SBV a -> SString
toString = literal . maybe "<symbolic>" show . unliteral
```

I get:

```
*Main> toString (2 :: SInt16)
"2" :: SString
*Main> toString (uninterpret "n" :: SInt16)
"<symbolic>" :: SString
```